# Input Text Align

Tags: css, forms

I have a two input text

```
<form action="process.php" method="get">
Link <input placeholder="Link" type="text" name="c">
<p>
<br>
Password <input placeholder="Password Admin" type="text" name="p">
<p>
<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

result:

[image]

How to align in this mode?

like this
[image]

Comment: You need to use css for this, something like `style="margin-left:200px;"`

Comment: `table` with `text-align: right` on the label cells #ignorethepurists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your text inside `label` elements with divs, and your inputs into another set of divs. Easy to modify their stylings then:

```
<form action="process.php" method="get" id="yourform">
    <div class="labels">
        <label for="c">Link</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
        <input placeholder="Link" type="text" name="c">
    </div>
    <div class="labels">
        <label for="p">Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
        <input placeholder="Password Admin" type="text" name="p">
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.labels {
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px
}
```

[See the demo - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsgj4/)